# How can I get rid of this reinterpret_cast, or is this usage OK?

Tags: c++, casting, function-pointers, reinterpret-cast

I have a template member function with this signature:

```
template<typename T> void sync(void (*work)(T*), T context);
```

It can be called with a pointer to a function that accepts an argument of type `T*`. `context` is passed to that function. The implementation is this:

```
template<typename T> void queue::sync(void (*work)(T*), T context) {
  dispatch_sync_f(_c_queue, static_cast<void*>(&context),
                  reinterpret_cast<dispatch_function_t>(work));
}
```

It uses `reinterpret_cast<>` and it works. The problem is that the standard doesn't define it very well and it is very dangerous. How can I get rid of this? I tried `static_cast` but that gave me a compiler error:

> `static_cast` from `void (*)(std::__1::basic_string<char> *)` to `dispatch_function_t` (aka `void (*)(void *)`) is not allowed.

`dispatch_function_t` is a C type and is the same as `void (*)(void*)`.

---

I'm not sure I was clear enough. What `dispatch_sync_f` does is it calls a given callback function and passes the given context parameter to that callback function. (It does that on another thread, although that is out of the scope of this question.)

Comment: If the context needs to be around when it is called in another thread, I'm about 99% sure using a pointer to a local variable will cause problems. The 1% is for taking into account that the function may never be exited but even then you might need some synchronization.

Comment: @Dietmar Kühl the thread is started immediately and the function blocks. This is not a problem.

Comment: Except that I didn't mention any approach on how to maintain the context I'm pretty sure that the correct solution is what I have outlined. The two dispatches may look expensive but are marginal compared to the needed synchronization.

Comment: @WTP Threads or not, if the `queue::sync` function returns before the callback occurs, you're hosed.  If the callback is in another thread, it has to wait until that thread has finished.  Explicitly.  (So it all depends on what `dispatch_sync_f` does.)

Comment: @James Kanze `dispatch_sync_f` waits until the thread has finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this is not supported by `static_cast` is because it is
potentially unsafe.  While a `std::string*` will convert implicitely to
a `void*`, the two are not the same thing.  The correct solution is to 
provide a simple wrapper class to your function, which takes a `void*`,
and `static_cast`s it back to the desired type, and pass the address of
this wrapper function to your function.  (In practice, on modern
machines, you'll get away with the `reinterpret_cast`, since all
pointers to data have the same size and format.  Whether you want to cut
corners like this is up to you—but there *are* cases where it's
justified.  I'm just not convinced that this is one of them, given the
simple work-around.)

EDIT: One additional point: you say that `dispatch_function_t` is a C type.  If this is the case, the actual type if probably `extern "C" void (*)(void*)`, and you can only initialize it with functions that have `"C"` linkage.  (Again, you're likely to get away with it, but I've used compilers where the calling conventions were different for `"C"` and `"C++"`.)

Answer (score 4):

I guess, you are not only casting `work` to `dispatch_function_t`, but calling it through `dispatch_function_t` pointer, aren't you? Such cast itself is valid according to standard, but all you can do with a casted pointer is cast it back to original type. Still your approach should work with most compilers and platforms. If you'd like to implement it so it's more standard conforming you can make a wrapper for your `context` and `work` function like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct meta_context_t
{
  T *context;
  void (*work)(T*);
};

template <typename T>
void thunk(void *context)
{
  meta_context_t<T> *meta_context = static_cast<meta_context_t<T> *>(context);
  meta_context->work(meta_context->context);
}

template<typename T> void queue::sync(void (*work)(T*), T context) {
  meta_context_t<T> meta_context =
  {
    &context,
    work
  };

  dispatch_sync_f(_c_queue, static_cast<void*>(&meta_context),
                thunk<T>);
}
```

Comment: @AJG85: I believe a lot of people can come with a solution like this independently.

Comment: True, but I'd still like to merge your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe this works or you have a rather narrow definition of "this works" (e.g. you found one particular setup where it seems to do what you think it should do). I'm not clear what `dispatch_sync_f()` does but I think it is suspicious that it gets a pointer to the local variable `context` as parameter. Assuming this variable outlives the use of this pointer, there is still a subtle problem which won't get you on most platforms but does get you on some:

C and C++ calling conventions can be different. That is, you cannot cast a pointer to a C++ function to a pointer to a C function and hope for this to be callable. The fix to this problem - and your original question - is, of course, an extra level of indirection: don't dispatch to the function you get as argument but rather dispatch to a C function (i.e. a C++ function declared as `extern "C"`) which takes its own context holding both the original context and the original function and calls the original function. The only [explicit] cast needed is the `static_cast<>()` restoring a pointer to your internal context from the `void*`.

Since you seem to implement a template you might need to use another indirection to get rid of this type: I don't thing function templates can be declared `extern "C"`. So you would need to restore the original type somehow e.g. using a base class and a virtual function or something like `std::function<void()>` holding a readily callable function object doing this conversion (a pointer to this object would be your context).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the cast to/from these two function pointer types is fine:

```
void(*)(void*)
void(*)(T*)
```

The problem is that you can't actually *use* the pointer that you have so cast. It's legal only to cast back to the original type (and those casts are `reinterpret_cast`, because these are unrelated types). From your code, I can't see how your actual callback function is defined. Why can't you accept a `dispatch_function_t` as your parameter for `queue::sync`, rather than casting it?

Comment: dispatch_function_t functions accept a void pointer but sync accepts a function that accepts a T pointer. Therefor, a cast is needed.

Comment: Officially, it's not.  In practice...  On a modern machine, you'll probably get away with it, but I've worked on machines (in the distant past) where `sizeof(void*) != sizeof(T*)`, unless `T` was `char`.

Comment: @JamesKanze, I think the casting is fine. It's the actual *use* of the pointer as the other type that is the problem:

"A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the pointed-to type, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @JamesKanze: that should be really distant past, since standard requires pointers to object types to be of equal size. This also means that code should (in practice) break only only if T has overloaded `operator&` or T is a function type (not function pointer one).

Comment: @huskerchad Yes.  The undefined behavior comes when he calls the function.

Comment: @KonstantinOznobihin Where?  This is a very recent addition if it is so (and an incompatibility with C).  There was certainly no such requirement in C++03.  The actual rules were designed to allow `char*` on word addressed machines, without increasing the size of all pointers.  (All pointers to class types must have the same size and representation, and `void*` and `char*` must have the same size and representation.  But there's nothing to require an arbitrary `T*` to have the same size and representation as a `void*`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I think, it's consequence of requirement that it should be possible to cast a pointer to some object type T1 to a pointer to some other object type T2 and back and get the original value. The only way to have different sizes for T1* and T2* is to have all values of bigger size to be invalid (trap representation) so reading such value is UB. Again, this is all about pointers to object types, not about arbitrary T*.

Comment: @KonstantinOznobihin There is no such requirement.  §4.10 (Pointer
conversions), says that a pointer to object can be converted to a
`void*`, but not to another pointer type..  §5.2.10  (`reinterpret_cast`)
says that the results of a `reinterpret_cast` between pointer types is
unspecified unless a certain number of conditions are met (target must
have stricter alignment than source).

Answer (score 0):

`reinterpret_cast` is guaranteed to work when converting from a type `T *` to `void *` and back. It is, however, not acceptable to cast from or to a pointer to a base or derived class of T.

The type of `work` needs to be `dispatch_function_t` in this case, and the first order of business in that function needs to be the cast from `void *` to `T *`. Implicitly casting the argument by using a different argument type and casting the function type is not allowed.

Rationale: the standard allows different pointer representations for different types, as long as all pointer types can be converted to `void *` and back, so `void *` is the "most precise" pointer type. A conforming implementation is allowed to clear the bottom-order bits of an `uint32_t *` if `sizeof(uint32_t) > sizeof(char)` (i.e. `sizeof(uint32_t) > 1`) or even shift the pointer value if the machine instructions can utilize these pointers more effectively; on a machine with tagged or shifted pointer values the `reinterpret_cast` is not necessarily a no-op and needs to be written explicitly.